# Form submission not posting data after previous preventDefault'd events

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, multipartform-data

I have a form which, when submitted, is first validated by a function that is bound to the form's "submit" event.  If the validation fails, the submit event has it's default action cancelled via `e.preventDefault()`.  If the form submits correctly the first time, it works.  If, however, it experiences a `preventDefault` then subsequent submissions do not send any form data in the POST request.  I analyse this in the Chrome code inspector. 
FYI it is a `multipart/form-data` form.

Is there any reason that the form would ignore all the inputs when submitting?

Comment: its really convoluted. I simplified the explanation when asking here just to eliminate the possibility that `preventDefault` does something weird. Hoping that someone here new something magical.  Otherwise, I'm assuming it's something strange I've done.

Comment: I never heard of this before that is why I was asking for some code, I assume there is something in there.

Comment: Okay i found my mistake.. Something I didn't know. I'm not allowed to answer my own question yet though, apparently. :P  The reason was that I had disabled the elements while waiting for the response from the server.  Disabled inputs apparently aren't submitted.

Comment: Told you it was code ;) I know readonly is submited but disabled is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.  Form elements that have the "disabled" attribute are not included in submission.  I was disabling form elements in order to disallow the user from editing things while waiting for response from the server (it is an asynchronous post to an iframe).